# Upload image from camera and gallery to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

As the title says, I am trying to upload images from both camera and gallery to firebase. But I have problems in both.

When I try to upload my image from the camera I get:

```
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
```

Even though my firebase rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try using the gallery I get:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at com.varroxsystems.plant.newPlant.Fileuploader(newPlant.java:192)
        at com.varroxsystems.plant.newPlant.access$100(newPlant.java:57)
        at com.varroxsystems.plant.newPlant$2.onClick(newPlant.java:162)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

And I get no data in the firebase real time database nor in the firebase storage.
But I use this exact code on another application and it works just fine.
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
 if (fragment3.isAdded()) {
                    EditText plantdetails = (EditText) fragment3.getView().findViewById(R.id.plantdetails);
                    if (plantdetails.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(newPlant.this, "I think you forgot something.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        plants plants = new plants();

                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newPlant.this);
                        prefs.edit().putString("pldetails", plantdetails.getText().toString()).apply();
                        String pname = prefs.getString("plname","null");
                        String pdate = prefs.getString("pldate","null");
                        String petails = prefs.getString("pldetails","null");
                        plants.setPlname(pname);
                        plants.setPldate(pdate);
                        plants.setPldetails(petails);

                        reference.child("Plants").child(pname).setValue(plants);
                        try {
                            Fileuploader();
                        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (fragment4.isAdded()){

                }
            }
        });

    }


    private void Fileuploader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String imageid;

        progress.showProgress(newPlant.this,"Loading...",false);
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
        Cursor getimage = databaseHelper.GetPath();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newPlant.this);
        String plname = prefs.getString("plname","null");
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;

        if (getimage !=null){
            while (getimage.moveToNext()) {
               Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage.getString(0));
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, out);
                imageid = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + (count++) + "." + getExtension(uri);
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Plants").child(plname).child("PlantImages");
                String imagekey = reference.push().getKey();
                reference.child(imagekey).child("ImageID").setValue(imageid);
                reference.child(imagekey).child("ID").setValue(count2++);

                System.out.println("IMAGES UPLOADEDDDD: " + imageid);
                byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
                StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(imageid);
                Ref.putBytes(data)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                                //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                //Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"Image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                progress.hideProgress();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(newPlant.this, Donenewplant.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                                DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
                                Cursor cursor2 = mDatabaseHelper.DeleteDataOfTableImagesAr();
                                cursor2.moveToNext();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                // ...
                                Toast.makeText(newPlant.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

            }


        }






    }

    private String getExtension(Uri uri)
    {
        ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void askFileReadPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(newPlant.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) + ContextCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(newPlant.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA) + ContextCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(newPlant.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (newPlant.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                            (newPlant.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)||ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (newPlant.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                Snackbar.make(newPlant.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        "Please Grant Permissions to upload plant photo",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                requestPermissions(
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                                .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
                            }
                        }).show();
            } else {
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
            }
        } else {
            alert();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean cameraPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean readExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if(cameraPermission && readExternalFile && writeExternalFile)
                    {
                        alert();
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(newPlant.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                "Please Grant Permissions to upload plant photo",
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                                new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        requestPermissions(
                                                new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                                        .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    private void alert() {
        new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(newPlant.this)
                .setTitle(null)
                .setMessage("Where would you like to get your picture from?")

                // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
                // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
                .setPositiveButton("Open Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                })
                // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
                .setNegativeButton("Open Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent gallery = new Intent();
                        gallery.setType("image/*");
                        gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Select Picture"), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .show();

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {



                File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);

                Log.d("tag", "ABsolute Url of Image is " + Uri.fromFile(f));
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
                databaseHelper.SavingimagepathAR(Uri.fromFile(f).getPath());
                plantimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                plantimage.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageproadd));
                plantimage.setClipToOutline(true);
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
                this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                System.out.println(databaseHelper.getProfilesCount());

                //uri = Uri.parse(cursor22.getString(0));
                plantimage.setImageURI(uri);







            }


        }

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null){
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri curi = item.getUri();
                            uri = item.getUri();
                            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(newPlant.this, curi));
                            //mArrayUri.add();
                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "." + getFileExt(curi);
                            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
                            databaseHelper.SavingimagepathAR(Uri.fromFile(imageFile).getPath());
                            Log.d("tag", "onActivityResult: Gallery Image Uri:  " + Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
//                                DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
//                                Cursor cursor22 = mDatabaseHelper.GetPath();
//                                while (cursor22.moveToNext()){
//                                    System.out.println("SELECTED " + cursor22.getString(i));
//                                }

                            plantimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                            plantimage.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageproadd));
                            plantimage.setClipToOutline(true);
                            //uri = Uri.parse(cursor22.getString(0));
                            plantimage.setImageURI(uri);


                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images ");
                    }else {
                        //Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"NO IMAGE EXCEPTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println(data.getData());
                        if (data.getData()!=null){
                            Uri contentUri = data.getData();
                            uri = data.getData();
                            System.out.println("CONTENT URI "+contentUri);
                            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(newPlant.this, uri));
                            System.out.println("FILE "+imageFile);
                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "." + getFileExt(uri);
                            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
                            databaseHelper.SavingimagepathAR(Uri.fromFile(imageFile).getPath());
                            Log.d("tag", "onActivityResult: Gallery Image Uri:  " + Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
                            //DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
                            //Cursor cursor22 = mDatabaseHelper.GetPath();

                            plantimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                            plantimage.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageproadd));
                            plantimage.setClipToOutline(true);
                            //uri = Uri.parse(cursor22.getString(0));
                            plantimage.setImageURI(uri);

                        }
                    }

                    // }

                }






            }

        }
    }


    private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString());
            return "";
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }


    private String getFileExt(Uri contentUri) {
        ContentResolver c = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(c.getType(contentUri));
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name


        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
//        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(newPlant.this,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.varroxsystems.plant.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if(bm==null) return; stop;

Comment: @blackapps it now does nothing. that doesn't solve anything rather that it just doesn't crash

Comment: You should also display a Toast() to inform the user about the error. Of course the bitmap is null and stays null. So now find out why the bitmap is null.

Comment: `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage.getString(0)); ` So bm becomes null; Now what was the value of `getimage.getString(0)` ? Is it a path to a file? What is the file size? And what is the resolution of the image?

Comment: yes, get 'image.getString(0)' is the path of the file I don't know thought what is the size and resolution because it is from the emulator camera

Comment: But tell the path!! I asked for that. Which path is it? File manager apps on the emulator will tell you the size. And if you display it in an imageviewer that will tell you the resolution.

Comment: `Cursor getimage = databaseHelper.GetPath();` Please change that for better readability to `Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.GetPath();`

Comment: What are you choosing ? A .jpg file? Give full path.

Comment: @blackapps Never mind, I fixed the first error with the gallery which showed me that the bitmap is null by adding:
      `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
Which I forgot in the mainfest file.
But now I get the same error at both the gallery and camera which is:
`no auth token for request `
For firebase